# Django ForeignKey on_delete - composition vs aggregation

Tags: django, oop, foreign-keys

Is on_delete=models.CASCADE representing composition and models.PROTECT aggregation?

Since one of the main differences between aggregation and composition is that with composition if the composed class is deleted, all the objects of the componing classes are delated by consequence, and since this doesn't happen with aggregation, is the statement above correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`CASCADE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE) and [`PROTECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) represent composition, since both imply that the child object cannot exist if the parent object is deleted. [`PROTECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) prevents you from deleting the parent if a child object exists and as you said [`CASCADE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE) will delete all child objects

[`SET_NULL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL), [`SET_DEFAULT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_DEFAULT) and [`SET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET) represent aggregation since in each case the "child" model object can continue existing when the parent is deleted